# module.exports is not working anymore in react 16.12.0 , was working in 16.7.0

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

maybe is not related to react, but a crete-react-app,
I've just move old code to a new project with a updated create-react-app and react.
I've use share files for react and nodejs appplication. But now on my react app i can't import on the old way:

```
const ISOtoDate = function (dateString, format = '') {
  //value.toLocaleDateString() +' '+ value.toLocaleTimeString();


  if ( !dateString) { // not accept null
    return '';
  }
  if (format === '-short-nice-') format = 'll';
  if (dateString.length > 11) { // never is for input text, can use names for month,etc
     //format = !format || format === '-nice-' ? 'D MMM YY HH:MM' : format;
     format = !format || format === '-nice-' ? 'D MMMYY (h:mm a)' : format;
  } else {
    if (format === '-nice-') format = 'D MMM YY';
    if (!format) format = 'DD-MM-YYYY'; // important this format for input text %% fuuture see i18n
  }
  return moment(dateString,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z").format(format);
};


module.exports = {
  ISOtoDate,
  tryParseJSON,
};
```

then these import is failing:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ISOtoDate } from '../../utils/commonutils';
```

I get this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'ISOtoDate' is not exported from '../../utils/commonutils'.
```

Look like the compilers see the commonutils.js file , but don't see the imports. I need to keep this way with modules.export

any solution?

Comment: Looks like correct error message. You should export `ISOtoDate` like `module.exports = {
  ISOtoDate
};`

Comment: sorry i made a msitake with the name

Comment: Is commonutils outside of `src` directory ?

Comment: what is the version of `react-scripts` in your `package.json`?